# show flash message on validation fails ( image validation ) (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to show a flash message when validation fails.
Currently the validation works but the flash message doesn't.
I suspect my if condition is wrong

```
public function update_avatar(Request $request,$username){
  $this->validate($request,[
    'avatar' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png|required'
  ]);
  if($request['avatar']==null){
    \Session::flash('message','Please choose a file first.');
    \Session::flash('alert-class', 'alert-warning'); 
    return redirect()->back();
  }
  if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
    $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
    $filename = time(). '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
    Image::make($avatar)->save('assets/src/uploads/avatars/' . $filename);
    $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();
    $user->avatar = $filename;
    $user->update();
  }
  return redirect()->route('myplace',['username' => $user->username]);
}
```

**EDIT**:
form code added:

```
     <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{route('profile',['username'=>$user->username])}}" method="post">


  <input type="file" size="15px" name="avatar"  >

  <button type="submit" name="avatar1" class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 " value="upload" style="margin-top: 20px; width: 78px !important; " >upload</button>
  <input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" name="_token">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to put `FlashMessage` in else and then try this.

Hope it helps

```
public function update_avatar(Request $request,$username){
  $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'avatar' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png|required'
            ]);
  if($validator->fails()){ 
    \Session::flash('message','Please choose a file first.');
    \Session::flash('alert-class', 'alert-warning'); 
    return redirect()->back();
  }
  if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
    $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
    $filename = time(). '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
    Image::make($avatar)->save('assets/src/uploads/avatars/' . $filename);
    $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();
    $user->avatar = $filename;
    $user->update();
  }
  return redirect()->route('myplace',['username' => $user->username]);
}
```

Comment: MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

Comment: Are you using `ResourceController` or you have manually defined this update method?

Comment: i changed route to put still not working. update method is defined manually

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133030/discussion-between-yash-chaudhary-and-jaymin-panchal).

Answer (score 0):

Currently your request fails on the validation.
So either use the validation built in to laravel or use if statements with the flash session.
If your request does not contain an avatar, it will never reach your if statement due too the failed validation.

If you do want to create custom messages in your validation take a look at [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-error-messages) link.

Comment: Then check with an if statement if the avatar is included (as you already do) and whether or not it is one of the accepted data types